LFS-enabled git clone stuck on 81%, always
git clone https://github.com/XX/XX.git
Cloning into 'XX'...
Username for 'https://github.com': XXX
Password for 'https://XXX@github.com': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 24897, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (46/46), done.
remote: Total 24897 (delta 3), reused 46 (delta 1), pack-reused 24849
Receiving objects: 100% (24897/24897), 492.50 MiB | 7.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12786/12786), done.
Updating files: 100% (24707/24707), done.ng files:  81% (20013/24707)

it always hangs on 81%, ive changed httpPOST buffer to large amount. There are no problems with pushing though. When stuck there is no network traffic as slurm says
if I do ctrl + c:
^Cwarning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'


Exiting because of "interrupt" signal.

Does it mean its okay?

Looks a bit like a bug in the print display  ... Updating files: 100% (24707/24707), done is not long enough to overwrite the entire line and the ng files:  81% (20013/24707) part looks like a leftover of a previous print that hasn't been correctly overwritten ... you should probably anyway wait until also the checkout has completed

in general HTTPS might sometimes hang up if things take longer ... consider using SSH

Did you try git status as the warning suggests? Seems it hangs at checkout.

It just needed to have more big files moved to LTS
